# Reading an Object from environment.getProperty()

Tags: java, spring, groovy

I am trying to read from `environment.getProperty()`. I am able to read to pass in a key and retrive, but now i am trying to read an object(so as to make the code generic).

So environment values are loaded from a JSON.
say:

```
{name:"xyz",class:"12"}
```

so when I pass in environment.getProperty("name") I get back xyz.

But I want to read something of this nature.

```
{student:[student1:{name:"xyz",class"12"}, student2:{name:"abc",class:"11"}]}
```

I tried using `environment.getProperty("student",List.class)` but that didn't resolve this.

Any comments?

Comment: Can you post your code, please.

Comment: I am no an expert of Spring, but this could be connected with generic type of List class. You have not defined what kind of objects will be in the list. Maybe a better way is to use SomeType[].class.

Comment: to be able to answer this question it is essential to know where environment comes from and what class it is. Otherwise this question simply missing information